# Web crawler doesn't print every image source

Tags: python, html, image, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am trying to make a web crawler that will give me all the links to images in the given URL, but many of the images that I found, while looking in the page source and searching in the page source with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, were not printed in the output.

my code is:

```python
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import os

print ("Which website would you like to crawl?")
website_url = raw_input("--> ")

i = 0
while i < 1:
    source_code = requests.get(website_url)  # The source code will have the page source (<html>.......</html>
    plain_text = source_code.text  # Gets only the text from the source code
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html5lib")
    for link in soup.findAll('img'):  # A loop which looking for all the images in the website
        src = link.get('src')  # I want to get the image URL and its located under 'src' in HTML
        if 'http://' not in src and 'https://' not in src:
            if src[0] != '/':
                src = '/' + src
            src = website_url + src
        print src
    i += 1
```

How should I make my code print **every** image that is in an `<img>` in the HTML page source?

For example: the website has this HTML code:

```html
<img src="http://shippuden.co.il/wp-content/uploads/newkadosh21.jpg" *something* >
```

But the script didn't print its `src`.

The script *is* printing the `src` in `<img .... src="...">`

How should I improve my code to find **all** the images?

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look on the main page of the domain you posted on the example, I see that the image you refer is not on src, but on data-lazy-src attribute.

So you should parse both attributes like:

```
src = link.get('src')
lazy_load_src = link.get('data-lazy-src')
```

Actually when running the example software you showed, the img src for the image newkadosh21 is printed, but it is an base64 like:

```
src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhAQABAPAAAP///wAAACwAAAAAAQABAEACAkQBADs="
```